# On clicking the page divs get selected and turn blue

Tags: html, css, mouse

This is really a vague question and I apologize for that. I'm building an application which is showing/hiding some divs. There are multiple views in application.

In some views, which I start clicking randomly, some div's get selected ( appear as default browser blue selection ) which is really annoying. In some views this behavior doesn't seem to occur. I want to know what might be the cause of this.

( since I don't know the cause it's really hard to create a jsfiddle or something to reproduce this case )

Comment: Without some example code or fiddle, it's nearly impossible to reproduce or troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: you could set the selection color transparent `::selection { background-color: transparent }`

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about the default text selection colour. Give the following a shot:

```
::selection {
    background: transparent;
}
```

I've no idea what browser support is like for ::selection I'm afraid

Comment: Browser support is for all browsers except IE <9

Answer (score 0):

in css:

```
a, img {  
 border-style: none;
}
```

i am assuming your divs have javascript attached via a elements?